# Jetty Websocket, closing session OpCode 12

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, chat, opcode

I've been working on a chat client-server using Jetty websockets and Java.
However I'm currently getting a strange error, while debugging my code (I won't post my code, as it is part of a larger and complex project, and i don't expect anybody to read all of it, except me)
But i'd like to know if any of you met a similar error, or know how to understand it ?

Whenever I try to connect with my client, as soon as the first HTTP request of the handshake reaches the server, and the upgrade is supposed to proceed, i get this error and the end of the handshake without any upgrade.

Error message taken from the client side:

```
 Session Opened:WebSocketSession[websocket=JettyAnnotatedEventDriver[amos.client.unpublic.test.yoko.websocket.AnnotatedSocket@4e33a461],behavior=CLIENT,connection=WebSocketClientConnection@68161ae2{FILLING}{f=Flusher[queueSize=0,aggregateSize=0,failure=null],g=Generator[CLIENT,validating],p=Parser@1c415223[ExtensionStack,s=START,c=0,len=0,f=null,p=WebSocketPolicy@44588a43[behavior=CLIENT,maxTextMessageSize=10000000,maxTextMessageBufferSize=10000000,maxBinaryMessageSize=10000000,maxBinaryMessageBufferSize=10000000,asyncWriteTimeout=60000,idleTimeout=300000,inputBufferSize=4096]]},remote=WebSocketRemoteEndpoint@3f32a8b7[batching=true],incoming=JettyAnnotatedEventDriver[amos.client.unpublic.test.yoko.websocket.AnnotatedSocket@4e33a461],outgoing=ExtensionStack[queueSize=0,extensions=[],incoming=org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketSession,outgoing=org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.io.WebSocketClientConnection]]
 2017-05-08T16:53:08.668    DEBUG   WebSocketClient@12654428-52 Parsing extra remaining buffer from UpgradeConnection
 2017-05-08T16:53:08.668    DEBUG   WebSocketClient@12654428-46-selector-WebSocketClientSelectorManager@5e31283d/0  Key interests updated 1 -> 0
 2017-05-08T16:53:08.668    DEBUG   WebSocketClient@12654428-46-selector-WebSocketClientSelectorManager@5e31283d/0  Local interests updated 1 -> 0 for SelectChannelEndPoint@6fbfc570{localhost/127.0.0.1:5080<->55844,Open,in,out,-,-,300000,WebSocketClientConnection}{io=0,kio=0,kro=1}
 2017-05-08T16:53:08.668    DEBUG   WebSocketClient@12654428-46-selector-WebSocketClientSelectorManager@5e31283d/0  Running change org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$1@2810e813
 2017-05-08T16:53:08.668    DEBUG   WebSocketClient@12654428-46-selector-WebSocketClientSelectorManager@5e31283d/0  FILL_INTERESTED-->FILLING WebSocketClientConnection@68161ae2{FILLING}{f=Flusher[queueSize=0,aggregateSize=0,failure=null],g=Generator[CLIENT,validating],p=Parser@1c415223[ExtensionStack,s=START,c=0,len=0,f=null,p=WebSocketPolicy@44588a43[behavior=CLIENT,maxTextMessageSize=10000000,maxTextMessageBufferSize=10000000,maxBinaryMessageSize=10000000,maxBinaryMessageBufferSize=10000000,asyncWriteTimeout=60000,idleTimeout=300000,inputBufferSize=4096]]}
 2017-05-08T16:53:08.668    DEBUG   WebSocketClient@12654428-52 terminateConnection(1,002,Unknown opcode: 12)
```

I've looked up the OpCode from the RFC 6455 :

```
|Opcode  | Meaning                               | Reference |
-+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------|
 | 0      | Continuation Frame                  | RFC 6455  |
-+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------|
 | 1      | Text Frame                          | RFC 6455  |
-+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------|
 | 2      | Binary Frame                        | RFC 6455  |
-+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------|
 | 8      | Connection Close Frame              | RFC 6455  |
-+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------|
 | 9      | Ping Frame                          | RFC 6455  |
-+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------|
 | 10     | Pong Frame                          | RFC 6455  |
-+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------|
```

But i don't get the meaning of the OpCode :12 in my debugging.

I suppose it is related to the fact that there are some data remaining in the buffer and the code isn't received/parsed properly, is it just an unproperly fragmented ping/pong frame ? Can it come from the fact that i have numerous servlet and this causes a conflict in the session treatment ?

EDIT: I am using jetty websocket API on both sides (server & client), i am using the 9.1.5 version.

I'd appreciate any hint or help !
Thanks a lot,
A curious programmer apprentice.

Comment: Request for clarification: are you using Jetty WebSocket on both ends, client *and* server?

Comment: My bad, i should have been more precise.
Yes, I am using the jetty API on both sides (the 9.1.5 version to be precise)

Comment: So the error shown is from client side, do you see anything on server side?

Comment: On the server side, there is no more information, the only information i get from debugging before the closure of the session is:
2017-05-08T17:40:27.591 DEBUG Idle pool thread Disconnected:  127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1)  (statusCode= 1,002 , reason=Unknown opcode: 12)

Comment: If it is systematic, and nobody comes up with a good idea, it would be great if you could isolate the issue and share an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Youri upgrade your version of Jetty.  You are using a very old (re: the first release of that WebSocketClient) codebase.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, i'll try to isolate the issue while solving it.
@JoakimErdfelt,  would you say it is really necessary, and mandatory to upgrade jetty to the latest version ? As the whole company software is running on the 9.1.5 version. I fear it might lead to a lot of changes and refactoring within the code.
So I'd prefer to avoid it, if it is possible, what do you think ?

Comment: I would strongly advise it, the websocket spec (and associated specs) have progressed immensely since those heady early days.  Your problems could be in Jetty's WebSocket impl, the various WebSocket extensions (eg: permessage-deflate), the browsers, the websocket proxies, and any number of intermediaries that have all had hundreds of updates for websocket since Jetty 9.1.5 was released.

Comment: Many of your problems can be explained with the early draft implementations of permessage-deflate extension present in Jetty 9.1.x.  The first time Jetty and the browsers aligned to a final spec was Jan 15, 2016.  Jetty 9.3.7.v20160115 was the first release with a stable permessage-deflate implementation.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt, Thank you for your explanation, it is now clear that upgrading is just a matter of time.
I will proceed to upgrading locally, and see the impact before pushing it to the rest of the company, in the case it goes well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay,
The error was coming from for the fact that in my collection of handler, i had two handler responsible for answering the request, which led to this unproperly fragmented answers. After assigning a correct path and only one handler it worked  without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

When the WebSocketClient received the network data, it proceeded to parse the WebSocket Frame (RFC6455).

When it got to the opcode parsing, it found that code to be 12, which is invalid (per spec), so it terminated the connection.

Comment: Indeed, however what I'm trying to understand, is the reason for this unsuccessful ping fragmentation which leads to this OpCode. I will keep this topic open as I hope to isolate the issue, and share it here with those it may interest.

Comment: If you are going to isolate, start with either disabling/unregistering the extensions (on either the client or server side).  You can also optionally just strip the extensions from the upgrade negotiation step.  Some suggestions on how to accomplish this (in Jetty 9.4) - https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1341